# Which is a better architecture? Multiple SPSC queues or a one MPSC queue?

Tags: c++, multithreading, low-latency

I'm writing a HFT application using C++, so low latency is really important. I use a lock-free queue implementation.

There are mainly 2 producer threads in my system, Producer1 and Producer2, and 1 consumer thread Consumer1.

Producer1 produces EventA and EventB
Producer2 produces EventA

There are two options as I see:
**Option1 - MPSC queue**
Producer1 push EventA to Q1
Producer1 push EventB to Q1
Producer2 push EventA to Q1
Consumer1 thread consumes Q1 in a loop.

**Option2 - Multiple SPSC queues and Single Consumer**
Producer1 push EventA to Q1
Producer1 push EventB to Q2
Producer2 push EventA to Q3 
Consumer1 thread consumes Q1, Q2, Q3 in a loop.

Hope it is clear...

In terms of performance, which option do you think is better?

Thanks in advance..

Comment: No general answer.   You'll need to test for representative use cases in your program, for each set of hardware it runs on, etc.   Even if there is a difference in performance, the options may result in events being consumed in different order- which, depending on what the consumer does, can affect behaviour.

Comment: You can implement a SPSC queue without using any atomic operation (only with memory barriers). So 2 SPSC queues (P1->C1 and P2->C1) may be an easy/ideal solution for this. But, what are the produce rates of P1 and P2 ? What are the sizes of EventA and EventB ? Are they pooled ? If yes, are they pooled from the same pool ? There may be other concerns (NUMA?) that I forgot to mention. It is better to test and benchmark both approaches !

Answer (score 1):

In terms of performance option 2 is better.

Reason being, you can use lock free circular queue whereby producers dont have contention with consumers. Since all the producers are now writing to separate queue. There is no contention at all.
Compare this with option 1, where all the producers have to compete for lock on q1.

Apart from performance, does the sequence of event processing matter? I presume it's not. If it is, then you need to factor those in while choosing the solution